# matlab - suppress error message backtrace

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I try to check if input argument is of specific type and throw error message like:

```
function test(input)
    if ~ischar(input)
        error('%s is invalid input type.', class(input));
    end
end
```

But Matlab shows error message with `backtrace`-information:

```
>> test(1)
Error using test (line 3)
double is invalid input type.
```

How can I turn off the line `Error using test (line 3)`?

I'm looking for something similar to `off backtrace` with `warning`: `warning off backtrace;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can. The closest I got was by defining my own error structure:

```
testerr.message = 'test';
testerr.identifier = '';
testerr.stack.file = '';
testerr.stack.name = 'Test Thing';
testerr.stack.line = 1;

error(testerr)
```

Which returns:

```
Error using Test Thing
test
```

As long as you keep the `file` field blank it will not display the line specified in the stack.

One potential workaround could be a combination of `fprintf` and `return`, courtesy of [Undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/changing-matlab-command-window-colors-part2):

```
function test(input)
    if ~ischar(input)
        fprintf(2, '%s is invalid input type.\n', class(input));
        return
    end
end
```

Depending on where this check resides in your real function you might need to get creative with how it exits, since `return` only kicks you back to the invoking function. Probably have it output a `True`/`False` flag?

Comment: yes, `fprintf` with colored text and `return` are what i am currently using to avoid `line number`, but same as you said, i have to return `boolean result` for ALL functions using this trick and even change other functions that call them, else the whole program will run like a mess. I will try the error structure and come back.